# Pipenv doesn't recognize virtual environment that was created by itself

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I'm new to `pipenv` and it might be some very newbie problem I'm facing.

I'm using `python 3.9` and installed `pipenv` using `python3 -m pip install pipenv`.

I have a project with a `requirements.txt` and after running `pipenv install -r requirements.txt` it was supposed to create a virtual environment but after running `pipenv shell` and `pipenv run src/manage.py runserver` it says:

`Error: the command src/manage.py could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts]`

The virtual environment was created at `/Users/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/project1-iLzXCwVe` and not at the working space. Is it possible it has something to do with that? Any way this can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run src/manage.py using the syntax `pipenv run` you will need to be in the root directory and either need to change your command to `pipenv run python src/manage.py` or make manage.py executable to leave it as `pipenv run src/manage.py`

Also note that you don’t need to use `pipenv run` if you are actively utilizing your virtual environment (which is activated by `pipenv shell`).